# Jenkins artifact plugin does not archive empty directories

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I use the Jenkins artifact plugin to downward streams to use. My problem is that despite all my efforts, empty folders are not being archived. Apparently .svn files are also not archived.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you are correct — empty directories cannot be archived, as a directory doesn't really make sense as an artifact in Jenkins.

If you're copying the artifacts to another job, you can just create the directory in the other job, or ensure the directory is archived in the first place by adding a `.keep` file (or so) and adding `**/.keep` to your list of artifacts to archive.

---

Regarding your second point that `.svn` files or directories are not archived, that is also correct since the *default* behaviour is to exclude certain patterns (e.g. `.git`, `*~`) when archiving artifacts.

To disable this behaviour, click on the <kbd>Advanced…</kbd> button below the "Archive the artifacts" post-build step, and uncheck the "Use default excludes" option.  Then your `.svn` artifacts can be archived.

Comment: well, my Ant build fails if the folder does not exist. I think the plugin is a bit too opinionated in this case...

Comment: Or your Ant build is too opinionated? :) The archiving is a core Jenkins feature — it's not a problem with the Copy Artifact plugin per se.

Comment: Just to clarify, so was it in any way possible to get Jenkins to archive the empty folders? Or is the workaround to create a dummy file in empty dirs?

Comment: Empty directories cannot be archived. Adding a dummy file to a directory and archiving that file will ensure the directory is archived.

Comment: I totally disagree that empty directories don't make sense. It's an output and if someone wants it archived it should be archived. There is an advanced option box and one of those options should be to archive empty folders. The workaround is to probably zip up the file structure (empty folders included) and archive the zip but it's a very unpleasant piece of additional work to work around the deficiencies in a plugin.

Comment: I also totally disagree with this answer. At some point empty dirs need to be left in place. When you "archive" something it should NOT be modified. By modifying, it is NO LONGER an archive of the source. With @ChristopherOrr logic, 'cp' and 'mv' should also erase empty dirs, but actually they DON'T.

Comment: @cmcginty I'm sorry that you disagree with my answer — but my answer, the workaround, and the additional information given, are correct. Just because you don't _like_ the behaviour of Jenkins described is not a reason to downvote the answer. I'm sorry if you find the behaviour frustrating, but there is a simple workaround and, as you've seen, the Jenkins issue tracker is the correct place for this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

same issue here, I come up with a workaround less agressevely if compared with a compressing and then stashing it.

`sh "find ${env.WORKSPACE} -type d -empty -exec touch {}/.empty \;"
stash name: "src", useDefaultExcludes: false, allowEmpty: true`

Then later on, to `unstash` do the folow:

`unstash "src"
sh "find ${env.WORKSPACE} -type f -name .empty -exec rm {} \+"`

Basically any empty diretories is added an empty file called `.empty`, then after unstash we just remove then. I understand is uggly once the plugin should handle properly what is requested, however until the ticket below get resolved, I have to move on.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9146

Comment: This helped us - but we had to add `\\;"` to the end, rather than `\;"` because of a Groovy compilation error in our Jenkinsfile. 

This is what we used: `sh 'find ${workspace} -type d -empty -exec touch {}/.empty \\;'`