# Missing Laravel Storage Folder

Tags: laravel, jenkins, laravel-5.1, jenkins-plugins, aws-code-deploy

I'm currently in the process of trying to deploy a Laravel 5 application to an AWS Ec2 instance. I'm using Jenkins CI with the AWS Code Deploy plugin, but I seem to be having issues. It looks like the Storage folder is being completely excluded from the projects directory. IE completely missing. I decided to follow up and launch a base Laravel 5 app just to test. It still drops off the Storage folder. Anyone have any idea why the Storage Dir is being dropped from the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note to anyone having this issue. It is on the Jenkins side. Jenkins zips the project and disregards any directories which are empty. The storage directory is completely empty therefore jenkins ignores it during its zip process.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8224

[Jenkins artifact plugin does not archive empty directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076769/jenkins-artifact-plugin-does-not-archive-empty-directories)